# How to identify source of periodic latency spikes during fpga writes in real-time Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, linux-device-driver

We are running Wind River real-time Linux on multi-core Intel Haswell cpus.  The kernel has the real-time patches applied.

We have to periodically (every 250us) program FPGA registers on a custom PCI board.  We achieve this using a KLM driver.

We find that, periodically, the FPGA writes take about 100us longer than usual, i.e. there is a periodic latency 'spike'.  The period of the spike is 1sec.  In other words, once every second the FPGA writes take about 100us longer to achieve than usual.  These longer writes are a problem for us as we can miss timing deadlines.

What sort of system activity might cause the driver to delay making the FPGA writes?

How might I identify the cause?

Comment: Did you try writing a `0` into `/dev/cpu_dma_latency`?

Comment: I have kernel boot parameter: intel_idle.max_cstate=0 which I think is equivalent.

Comment: You need to partition this into: is my driver getting consistently scheduled, or is my hardware (fpga) the cause of my latency.   Timestamps are your friend here, you can bracket the code which writes the register to time how long the register write takes, and panic if there is substantial variance.    Similarly,  your driver can log the 'before' timestamp, and compare it to previous log entries to see if it is being scheduled properly.  If it is the latter (hardware) re-read your books and instrument it; if it is the former, look to competing interrupts and priorities.